# LINUX and C : What does it mean this condition, and how to install the required packages in order to return true

Tags: c

Using linux ubuntu with metasploit framework, i have a shell script which contains the following lines in the first begining of the file. At first glance i thought that i should install the the mingw32 package, so i uses the following line in terminal 
        apt-get install mingw32-runtime mingw-w64 mingw gcc-mingw32 mingw32-binutils

but when i compile the below script, it still says that i must install mingw-w64n binutilis-mingw......etc

```
   #Lets check for MinGW32
   if  builtin type -p i686-w64-mingw32-gcc > /dev/null ; then 

   echo "Here is a network device list available on yor machine"
   else echo "Please install the mingw-w64, binutils-mingw-w64, gcc-mingw-w64, mingw- w64-dev, mingw-w64-tools"
   echo "exiting.....";  exit
```

Could some one help me what to write in the terminal in order to get the required packages installed with my linux ubuntu

Comment: Did you try `apt-get install install mingw-w64n binutilis-mingw` ?

Answer (score 2):

It calls the bash builtin `type` with an option `-p` to find out the path to binary if one exists. Then it discards unneeded output and spits message if the command failed (it fails if there's no binary in sight).

to install packages use the `apt-get install mingw-w64 or whatever...`/

Comment: mingw-w64 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 python-pyicu libdebian-installer4 cryptsetup
  libecryptfs0 reiserfsprogs rdate bogl-bterm ecryptfs-utils libdebconfclient0
  dmraid keyutils
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.

Comment: What about the rest? Like `gcc-mingw-w64` etc?